# Bash complete with "@"-sign

Tags: bash, autocomplete, scp, bash-completion

I am trying to create an autocomplete script for scp.
The script reads the user and hostname from my .ssh/config file
My .ssh/config file looks like:

```
Host host1
    HostName host1
    User userA
    port 22

Host host2
    HostName host2
    User userB
    port 22

Host host3
    HostName host3
    User userB
    port 22
```

My .autocomplete_scp.sh file is:

```
# SSH
function _scp_completion() {
    pcregrep -o -M 'HostName [a-zA-Z.]+[\n\t\s]+User [a-zA-Z]+' 
    $HOME/.ssh/config | awk 'NR % 2 == 1 { o=$2 ; next } { print $2"@"o}'
}

complete -W "$(_scp_completion)" scp
```

I source this file in my bashrc.

Now when I type `userA` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the autocomplete function will give me `userA@host1`. When I type `userB` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the autocomplete function will give me `userB@`, but I am not able to get the full string (`userB@host2` or `userB@host3`).

It also doesn't work when I type `userA@h` and hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button twice. So it seems to get stuck due to the `@` sign.
(When I remove the `@` sign from the _scp_completion function it works fine.)

Any ideas to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Not actually answering your question, but are you aware that bash-completion contains a very sophisticated [completion for `scp`](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/completions/ssh#L398)?

Comment: The pattern `HostName [a-zA-Z.]+` does not match `HostName host1`.

Comment: @EmilyE. Yes true, but in my case the hostnames don't contain any digits. Nonetheless, If I change the pattern to `HostName [a-zA-Z0-9.]`, I will still have the same issue.

Comment: @BenjaminW. It wasn't working for me, that's why I considered writing this script. However, now that I source both the bash-completion and my autocompletion script, it does work as it should. (But it doesn't solve the issue for my script unfortunately.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to make it work is to remove `'@'` from `$COMP_WORDBREAKS` or Bash would handle `@` by itself. You can try like this:

```
COMP_WORDBREAKS=${COMP_WORDBREAKS//@}
complete -W 'userA@host1 userB@host2 userB@host3' scp
```

---

According to bash doc:

> `COMP_WORDBREAKS`
>
> > The  set of characters that the *readline* library treats as word separators when performing word completion.